# OpenSSL 1.1.1c with Weak Ciphers

Tags: openssl, centos8

Does anyone know how to enable tlsv1 support on openssl on Centos:8 natively?

I have tried to compile from source using `enable-weak-ssl-ciphers enable-deprecated enable-rc4 enable-tls1` but it's still not allowing me to run openssl s_client without specifying tlsv1 or curl without the RC4 ciphers

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer to the problem; No need to recompile the code

`update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY`

and restart the service that is supposed to be providing the TLS1
server or reboot the machine.

The LEGACY crypto policy purpose is exactly for re-enabling some of the
not-up-to-date protocols and crypto algorithms.